# How to insert a hyperlink to a python dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, hyperlink

I have a dataframe as given below [input_dataframe]. I want the column Number to display as a clickable hyperlink.
For e.g., under column Number, I want it to be displayed as 1234, but it should be as hyperlink and the link should be taken from the next column.

I tried the following code, but it is showing the entire hyperlink from the 2nd column twice in the first column [Output_dataframe]. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\Test_1.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet1')
df['Number'] = '<a href=' + df['url'] + '><div>' + df['url'] + '</div></a>'
df.to_excel("Test_2.xlsx",index=False)
```

[image: input_dataframe]

[image: Output_dataframe]

Comment: This works!!!
def make_clickable(Number, url):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(Number,url)

df['Number'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_clickable(x['url'], x['Number']), axis=1)
df.style
a = df.to_html(index=False,render_links=True, escape=False)

Answer (score 0):

Can't test but believe this should work:

```
df["Number"] = df["url"].apply(lambda x: f"=HYPERLINK({x}, {x})")
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I tried this and getting the output as follows in column Number: 
<a href=https://jira/browse/1234>https://jira/browse/1234 </a>

Comment: Try edit my original answer was for html but excel uses =HYPERLINK

Comment: This doesn't work either. It shows all the values in the Number as 0